# Smoothen transition for order of bars in d3 chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, bar-chart

I am allowing users to order the data in their bar chart either chronologically or in descending order from highest to lowest based on a metric of their choosing.

The height of the bars themselves are smoothly transitioning, but when descending order is chosen, the order of the array of data changes, meaning the order of the bars need to change as well. Right now, the new data in this case just flashes its update (without any smooth animation). Where would I build in this additional transition? Or even better, how would I target this?

```
scope.render = function(data){
    if (scope.metric !== "") {
        var maximumY = d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return eval('d.' + scope.metric);
        });
        x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.id; }));
        y.domain([-(maximumY * .01), d3.max(data, function(d) { return eval('d.' + scope.metric); })]);
        chart.select(".x.axis").remove();
        chart
            .append("g")
            .append("line")
            .attr('x1',0)
            .attr('x2',width)
            .attr('y1',height )
            .attr('y2',height)
            .attr('stroke-width','2')
            .attr("class", "domain");

        chart.select(".y.axis").remove();
        chart.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", -40)
            .attr('class','label')
            .attr("x", -height)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "begin")
            .text(scope.label);

        var bar = chart.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data, function(d) { return d.id; });

        // new data:
        bar.enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "bar-container")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr('fill','#4EC7BD')
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.id); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(eval('d.'+scope.metric)); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(eval('d.'+scope.metric)); })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .on('click', function(d){
                scope.showDetails(d, eval('d.'+scope.metric))
            })

        // removed data:
        bar.exit().remove();
        // updated data:
        bar
            .transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(eval('d.'+scope.metric)); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(eval('d.'+scope.metric)); });

    }
};
```

Let me know if there is anything additional I can provide.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or plunker to see where it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1429426)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I hadn't, thank you. It looks like I need a transform attribute, but I'm not sure how to make that happen. Would you be able to help at all?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the example implements all of what you want, so you just have to adapt the code for your case.